# Using Jolt for json transformation :

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I'm expecting the format of Input and output json will be same with one field modification i.e. name to firstname. Further leads would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Input Json :

```
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "name": "Pankaj Kumar",
    "permanent": true,
    "address": {
      "street": "El Camino Real",
      "city": "San Jose",
      "zipcode": 95014
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
      9988664422,
      1234567890
    ],
    "role": "Developer"
  },
  {
    "id": 124,
    "name": "Rahul Dravid",
    "permanent": false,
    "address": {
      "street": "Baner",
      "city": "Pune",
      "zipcode": 95014
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
      9988664422,
      1234567890
    ],
    "role": "Product owner"
  }
]
```

Spec json :

```
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": "id",
        "name": "firstname",
        "permanent": "permanent",
        "address": "Employee address",
        "phoneNumbers": "phoneNumbers",
        "role": "role",
        "fname": "fname"
      }
    }
    }
]
```

Output json :

```
[ {
  "id" : 123,
  "name" : "Pankaj Kumar",
  "permanent" : true,
  "address" : {
    "street" : "El Camino Real",
    "city" : "San Jose",
    "zipcode" : 95014
  },
  "phoneNumbers" : [ 9988664422, 1234567890 ],
  "role" : "Developer",
  "fname" : "fname"
}, {
  "id" : 124,
  "name" : "Rahul Dravid",
  "permanent" : false,
  "address" : {
    "street" : "Baner",
    "city" : "Pune",
    "zipcode" : 95014
  },
  "phoneNumbers" : [ 9988664422, 1234567890 ],
  "role" : "Product owner",
  "fname" : "fname"
} ]
```

Expected OUTPUT JSon :

```
[ {
  "id" : 123,
  "firstname" : "Pankaj Kumar",
  "permanent" : true,
  "address" : {
    "street" : "El Camino Real",
    "city" : "San Jose",
    "zipcode" : 95014
  },
  "phoneNumbers" : [ 9988664422, 1234567890 ],
  "role" : "Developer",
  "fname" : "fname"
}, {
  "id" : 124,
  "name" : "Rahul Dravid",
  "permanent" : false,
  "address" : {
    "street" : "Baner",
    "city" : "Pune",
    "zipcode" : 95014
  },
  "phoneNumbers" : [ 9988664422, 1234567890 ],
  "role" : "Product owner",
  "fname" : "fname"
} ]
```

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Use shift operation, to change the name to firstname

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": "[&1].id",
        "name": "[&1].firstname",
        "permanent": "[&1].permanent",
        "address": "[&1].address",
        "phoneNumbers": "[&1].phoneNumbers",
        "role": "[&1].role",
        "#fname": "[&1].fname"
      }
    }
  }
]
```